# Is there a difference between bitshift by a constant versus bitshifting by a variable with the same value, in C?

Tags: c, bit-shift

I'm attempting to bitshift the value `0xFFFFFFFF` by 32 bits, and it correctly comes to
0 if I write

```
x = x << 32;
```

however it stays as `0xFFFFFFFF`

when I write:

```
x = x << y
```

when `y = 32`

I really don't understand this at all.

I need to be able to use a variable though, for a function that shifts by `32 - n`

**Edit**

If `<< 32` is undefined, then I really can't perceive a way to create a function that pads n - upper bits with 1's

Comment: If `x` is 32 bits that is undefined behavior.

Comment: Answering your edit: you have two solutions: either make a special case or use a wider type than `int` (it is as simple as `(int)(0xFFFFFFFFull << y)`. The conversion from `unsigned long long` back to `int` is implementation-defined and does what you want for most implementations).

Comment: `if (y>=32) x= MIN_INT;`

Comment: @PascalCuoq or use a lookup table and avoid branching.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? You can usually get a warning for this.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour GCC will only warn if it is quite sure that the shift is illegal. I work on a static analyzer that warns as soon as it is unable to prove that the shift is legal, and that is a completely different tool used by completely different persons.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I understand, I did say `usually`, but at least in the first case it seems like the compiler should be able to tell but w/o seeing an SSCCE I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to shift by the bit length of a variable or greater. From the draft C99 standard section `6.5.7` *Bitwise shift operators*:

> [...]If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

As Pascal says, you need to make a special case or use a wider type.

`gcc` in some cases can generate a warning for this [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a1c16a0e1f82333):

> warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]

Answer (score 1):

Shifting a variable by the number of bits it contains, or more, is undefined behavior. Assuming that `x` is 32 bits, there is no "correct" result.

The compiler that I use identifies this programming error:

```
x.c:3:3: error: left shift count >= width of type [-Werror]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference of behavior if `y` is of type `int` (because the literal `32` is also of type `int`) and if your program has defined behavior.

If `x` is of a `32` bits wide type, your program invokes undefined behavior, so everything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do as follow:

```
unsigned int x;
unsigned long bx = ((unsigned long)x)&0xFFFFFFFFUL;
int n = 0; // put whatever you have
int y = 32-n;
bx = bx << y;

x = bx&0xFFFFFFFFUL;
```

Comment: depending on your actual processor word-length, you may have to use unsigned long long, of course.

Comment: On some system, `unsigned long long` and `unsigned int` may be the same length.