# left shift operation in C doesnt work as expected

Tags: c, gdb

I am running GDB  through a snippet of code which is doing a left shift of 1 by 10000.

Here is the code

```
uint32_t x = (1 << y )
```

The value of y is 10000.

I was expecting a value of 0 for x, but I see that x has a value of 65536. Quite strange.

GDb also shows this behavior

```
(gdb) p 1<<10000
$52 = 65536
(gdb) p 1<<9984
$54 = 1
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: It is undefined behavior to [shift by the bit length of a variable or greater](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21894503/1708801)

Comment: If X doesn't work as expected, most likely it's your expectations that need fixing.

Comment: if my memory is correct, gcc will wrap over the number into the valid zone, i,e, `1<<10000 == 1 << (10000 % (8 * sizeof(uint32_t)))`.

Comment: @haccks I really dislike cross tag duplicates, we can't find a highly upvoted C version?

Comment: It reminds me of TI C6000 that can do bitshift using either shifter or multiplier. Shifter version wraps right hand into 0-31 while the multiplier version saturates right hand to -31 or +31 and used sign to determine directionality.